# XML to Json Conversion issues defining arrays

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9, marklogic-dhf

I have below xml and InsID is in 2 places, first one is directly under PartyDownloadInfo and  occurs only once and ItemId is under PartyM element also and here it is repeated and occurs multiple times. During the conversion of xml to JSON how to custom define ItemId as an array only under PartyM. Giving below how I added in array in JSON conversion code and not giving me epxected result thus resulting ItemId as as array in both places.

```
JsonConfig['array-element-names'] = ['ItemId']



<tns:PartyDownloadInfo>
<tns:ItemId>
<tns:InsId>100000</tns:InsId>
<tns:EffectiveDt>2019-04-23</tns:EffectiveDt>
</tns:ItemId>
<tns:PartyM>
<tns:ItemId>
<tns:InsId>111111</tns:InsId>
</tns:ItemId>
<tns:ItemId>
<tns:InsId>122222</tns:InsId>
</tns:ItemId>
</tns:PartyM>
</tns:PartyDownloadInfo>
```

actual result of my Json Conversion Code:

```
{
  "PartyDownloadInfo": {
    "ItemId":[ 
      {
        "InsId": "100000", 
        "EffectiveDt": "2019-04-22" 
      }
    ],
    "PartyM": {
      "ItemId": [
        {
          "InsId": "111111"
        },
        {
          "InsId": "122222"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

expected result should be:

```
{
  "PartyDownloadInfo": {
    "ItemId": {
      "InsId": "100000", 
      "EffectiveDt": "2019-04-22" 
    },
    "PartyM": {
      "ItemId": [
        {
          "InsId": "111111"
        },
        {
          "InsId": "122222"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your XML is not valid so it is difficult to see what's going on here. Closing tag tns:InsurerId doesn't match opening tag tns:InId, closing tag ItemIdInfo doesn't match opening tag ItemId and so on.

Comment: corrected xml , my requirement is to make ItemId  as array only under PartyM but not directly under PartyDownloadInfo.

Comment: Hi corrected xml and Json, please advise.

Comment: What code are you using to convert to JSON?